# Reverse SSH tunnel techniques or procedures?

Tags: ssh, networking, firewall, remote, port-forwarding

What are the techniques to `SSH` into a machine which is behind NAT and at least not forwarding `SSH` ports, perhaps behind a firewall?

What I've come across is [teleport](https://github.com/gravitational/teleport), but I'm not quite sure that it's the best approach -- doesn't seem to be a [package](https://askubuntu.com/q/1004771/45156) for it.  Rather than `SSH` *into* the remote machine, would want the inverse, that the remote machine issues an "invite" to `SSH`.

Looking for technically easy and simple, not necessarily [best or most secure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108088/17056) practice.  Ideally the "invite" would persist so the the local machine can initiate the reverse `SSH` tunnel at any time.

Comment: There are a ton of tutorials on how to do this, like this one: https://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling